# Access crosstab prompting for date range criteria several times

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have several Access crosstab queries that prompt the user for a date range.

These queries prompt repeatedly before the query produces results.

The number of times the query prompts for the date range is equal to the number of columns in the output. For example, a query showing results by month, including a total column over a six month period will prompt eight times (for columns "supplier", "total" and each of the six months). A different query which shows results by two categories, will prompt four times ("supplier", "total", "category 1", "category 2".

Any help would be gratefully received.

```
PARAMETERS [Forms].[Date_Range].[Start_Date] DateTime, [Forms].[Date_Range].[End_Date] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Round(Sum([VAT_Amount]),2) AS Expr1
SELECT [All_Invoices_18-19].Supplier, Sum([All_Invoices_18-19].VAT_Amount) AS [Total Of VAT]
FROM [All_Invoices_18-19]
WHERE ((([All_Invoices_18-19].Invoice_Date) Between [Forms].[Date_Range].[Start_Date] And [Forms].[Date_Range].[End_Date]))
GROUP BY [All_Invoices_18-19].Supplier
PIVOT [All_Invoices_18-19].MFS;
```

C Perkins. Thanks for your interest in my post. In answer to your questions: 
1) Access Version: 14.0.7128.5000 (32-bit) Part of Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010
 2) Source Type: A local table
3) See below
 [All_Invoices_18-19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwAYp.png)
4) Number of records in source: 199,790
A SELECT query prompts for the date range only once.
The data is sensitive and so I cannot show an example. I can confirm however that every record in the source contains a value in the fields being used by the query.

Comment: After creating a mock-up of the table from columns in the query, I cannot reproduce the behavior.  It only prompts one time for each parameter.  To assist in reproducing the behavior or finding a solution, provide 1) Access version;  2) Source type--in other words, is `[All_Invoices_18-19]` a local table, a query, or a linked table;  3) Source table schema--column data types, especially of `[Invoice_Date]`; 4) Number of records in source.  Please edit the question with these details, not in comments.

Comment: Also, what is the behavior if you run only a SELECT query?  Does it also prompt more than once for each parameter?  In other words, remove the TRANSFORM and PIVOT clauses and add the PIVOT column to the GROUP BY clause like `GROUP BY [All_Invoices_18-19].Supplier, [All_Invoices_18-19].MFS`.

Comment: Prompts for values indicate those columns do not exist in table. Please show a sample of *[All_Invoices_18-19]* with columns.

Comment: @Parfait  Prompts are also for explicit parameters specified in a query, just as those listed in the example statement.  The question indicates that it is asking for the *same* parameter values multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

you have some sort of cockpit error - - as suggested - take a step back and first resolve as a simple Select query before moving on the Cross tab.  Also this is the format for parameters: [Forms]![Date_Range].[Start_Date] rather than just [Forms].[Date_Range].[Start_Date]

Comment: Fortunately I am not in an airplane, so there is no cockpit error. You will see from my post that I have already tried a SELECT query. Microsoft support does not give your suggestion for the format of parameters. However thanks anyway.

Comment: a repeating prompt, in a query, is typically a calculated field - where it is calling a value in from another object - and the reason for the prompt is that it cannot find that value.  And the reason it repeats is because it is re-firing for every record of the query results.  So really do double check your names and syntax in your calculated fields.